# Android Search in string and "Trim"

Tags: java, android, string, trim

So I got a huge string, and I start searching for

```
"<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>"
```

and

```
"</b></div>"
```

just like this: (It's actually an IF Statement.)

```
htmlCode.contains("<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>") 
&& htmlCode.contains("</b></div>")
```

Anyhow,after the first `"<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>"` there comes text, and after the text, there comes the second piece. (`"</b></div>"`)

Now, I want to 'GET' that piece of text, and eventually remove to other text, and just keep the 'Middle Text'.

I've been searching for a while now, couldn't find a solution.

If you could post me a link for a documentation, or maybe an example, that would be great.

**Extra Information:**

```
   /*
    * 1. Search for "<div style="font-size:15px;"><b>" ** TITLE COMES HERE **
    * 2. Search for "</b></div>" ** This is after the Title, so Title is between 1 and 2.
    * 3. Search for "<div style="float:left;"><a href="" ** Link Comes Here **
    * 4. Search for "" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">" ** Same as 2. // Link Instead ** 
    * 
    * -- How it should do it --
    * 1 -> Wait -> 2 -> Wait -> Get the text between 1 and 2 -> Save in String (Array) -> 3 -> Wait -> 4 -> Wait
    * -> Get the text between 3 and 4 -> Save in String (Array) -> Repeat Process (Max 25(?)).
    */
```

An example of the full string would be:

```
<div style="font-size:15px;"><b>**My Little Pony.**</b></div>
```

(The starred text is what I WANT to get)

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the index of first piece htmlCode.indexOf(""), and use htmlCode.substring(int start, int length) to find the text between to pieces.

```
int index1 = htmlCode.indexOf("<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>");
int index2 = htmlCode.indexOf("</b></div>");

String textInsideDiv = htmlCode.substring(index1+"<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>".length(), index2);
```

Comment: First of all, Thanks for reply'ing..
How would that work exactly? I mean, My string char count is over 1.000, plus, I don't know at what offset the specified string starts. Even tho I don't think that matters, Won't it go until the end of the whole string instead of my second piece of string? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! I kept making things more complicated in my head.. Didn't know it would be this easy!

Answer (score 2):

You should use java regexps, look in here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

**6.4. Building a link checker**

below is sample doing such extraction

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      Pattern  htmltag = Pattern.compile("<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>(.*?)</b></div>");
      String subjectString =             "<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>**My Little Pony.**</b></div>";
      Matcher tagmatch = htmltag.matcher(subjectString);
      while (tagmatch.find()) {
        System.out.println(tagmatch.group(1));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I guess I'm spending my night(s) reading that. I like the way it's being done. Altho, Is there a simpler way to Get the text between 2 pieces? +1 on the answer anyway

Comment: You can parse it manually using `indexOf` but you will only reproduce what regexps will do better and probably faster.